# Remove spaces between transpose value, comma separated in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, concatenation, transpose, array-formulas

Can someone tell me how to remove the spaces between the values. I can't workout if or how the JOIN function should be applied?

The desired outcome should be like: `VALUE,VALUE,VALUE`

Not: `VALUE, VALUE, VALUE`

[Google Sheet to play with](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/114etB0Jhx8AILuQRNFKjPzhwuKxIHiiWxFJxFg2Y_MU/edit?pli=1#gid=0) - Cell i2 contains the formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(UNIQUE(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN({B2:B, 
 SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(B2:B=TRANSPOSE(B2:B), 
 TRANSPOSE(A2:A)&",", )),,ROWS(B2:B))))&"|", ",|", )}, COUNTA(B2:B), 2)), ", ", ","))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution. I want to add one more column. Can you have a go at this please? Thank you! I have added a new Sheet 3 here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/114etB0Jhx8AILuQRNFKjPzhwuKxIHiiWxFJxFg2Y_MU/edit?pli=1#gid=846349561

Comment: Hi, thanks for adding to the formula. It's not quite right, the primary column is Sales ID, where only a single instance should be visible. Then all State & New ID must be comma separated with no spaces in the next two columns. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your column C contians the formula

`=JOIN(", ",FILTER(A:A,B:B=B2))`

### You specified `", "` as the delimiter.

If you do not desire to have spaces between the values change your delimiter from `", "` to `","`:

`=JOIN(",",FILTER(A:A,B:B=B2))`

Comment: You checked the wrong cell. Please check i2 which says "New York". Thanks

Comment: I cannot see any `join` function in cell I2. And what do you mean then by `VALUE,VALUE,VALUE`? whata re the values you are referring to and where are they contained?

Comment: If you look at cells J2 to K7, you'll see the values separated by a comma and space. But I just want a comma and no space. Thanks

Comment: I see. This can be done with Regex, as player0 just showed.